# Enity Framework Issue-

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have table name M_Lovs with columns TITLE,TYPE_ID,IS_ACTIVE,AMD_BY,AMD_ON and ID. ID is primary key and its autoincremented. When i try to save my table using entity framework it throws  **'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'**.. when i checked the inner exception i found **'{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}'** exception.
My code is as follows

```
M_LOVS lov = new M_LOVS();
                    lov.TITLE = masterData.Title;
                    lov.TYPE_ID = masterData.Type;
                    lov.IS_ACTIVE = masterData.IsActive ? 1 : 0;
                    lov.AMD_BY = addedBy;
                    lov.AMD_ON = DateTime.Now;
                    dbContext.M_LOVS.Add(lov);

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Debug and check the inner exception. It's usually some validation message saying that you're missing a field that's required.

Comment: i have checked it...it says 'unique constraint (SWDYNMC_DEV.M_LOVS_PK) violated\nORA-06512: at line 4'..But in my code i am not inserting any ID. as it will be auto incremented.

Comment: Ok. Then it sounds as you haven't told EF to use identity for your ID-column. Add this as an attribute to your id-column: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, and also `[Key]` if you didn't already.

Comment: In Entity framework i have set StoreGeneratedPattern= **Identity** for ID column

Comment: can you please share you DbContext and Entity class so that I can try on my system